# How can I show that $nb^{n-1}>b^{n-1}+b^{n-2}a+\cdots+a^{n-1}$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality

I'm trying to show that $$nb^{n-1}>b^{n-1}+b^{n-2}a+\cdots+a^{n-1}$$ when $0<a<b$. I'm aware of $$\begin{align}b>a&\implies a^{n}b^{n-1}\cdot b >a^{n}b^{n-1}\cdot a \\&\implies a^{n}b^{n}>a^{n+1}b^{n-1}\end{align}$$ which suggests that all successive terms following $b^{n-1}$ are less than $b^{n-1}$. However, I don't know **how to connect those individual inequalities** based on the axioms of ordered field, and its resulting properties to make the final statement.

Comment: You could just add all the inequalities you have.

Comment: Example: if $a<b$ and $c<d$, then $a+c<b+d$.

Comment: $b^{n-1} > b^{i} a^{n-1-i}$. You add up all inequalities, from $i=0$ to $n-1$

Comment: @CheeHa It would be great if you prove that's safe in the real field.

Comment: You can show that $b^k>a^k$ for all k using induction, so $b^{n-1-i}>a^{n-1-i}\implies b^{i}b^{n-1-i}>b^{i}a^{n-1-i}\implies b^{n-1}>b^{i}a^{n-1-i}$

Comment: @user84413 What is that you're proving? I think I've already proved it on my question.

Comment: I was just trying to give a way to justify the inequality that SiXUlm suggested using, employing the properties of an ordered field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take some term and do this :

$$a^ib^{n-1-i}=a \cdot a^{i-1} \cdot b^{n-1-i}<b \cdot a^{i-1} \cdot b^{n-i-1}=a^{i-1} \cdot b^{n-i}$$

Now continue extracting one $a$ at a time to get :

$$a^ib^{n-i-1}<a^{i-1}b^{n-i}<a^{i-2}b^{n-i+1}<\ldots<a \cdot b^{n-2}<b^{n-1}$$

This means every term is less than $b^{n-1}$ and because there are $n$ terms , the whole sum will be less than $nb^{n-1}$ .

**EDIT** At the request of Il-seob Bae here's a proof of the addition of inequalities on $\mathbb{R}$ .

Suppose $a>b$ and $c>d$ .We need to prove that $a+c>b+d$ .

I'll use three axioms :

$1)$ If $x>y$ then $x+z>y+z$.

$2)$ If $x>y$ and $y>z$ then $x>z$ .

$3)$ $x+y=y+x$

From axiom $1)$ :

- $a+c>b+c$ because $a>b$ .
- $c+b>d+b$ because $c>d$.

From axiom $3)$ :

- $b+c=c+b$ and $d+b=b+d$

Now use the axiom $2)$ of transitivity for $a+c>b+c$ and $b+c>b+d$ to get :

$a+c>b+d$ which proves the claim .

Comment: I'm already aware of that every term is less than $b^{n-1}$. My question is how to connect those inequalities in order to say that the whole sum is less than $nb^{n-1}$. What I mean by those inequalities is like $b^{n-1}>b^{n-2}a, \cdots, b^{n-1}>a^{n-1}$. In summary, I expected a proof that adding inequalities in the real field is safe.

Comment: @Il-seobBae   I added a proof that addition preserves the inequality .

Comment: Such a concise proof. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Hint : Replace all $a$ s with $b$ s

Since $0<a<b$ ,

$b^{n-1}\cdot a^0+b^{n-2}a^1+b^{n-3}a^2+\cdots+b^0\cdot a^{n-1}<b^{n-1}\cdot b^0+b^{n-2}b^1+b^{n-3}b^2+\cdots+b^0 \cdot b^{n-1}$

$b^{n-1}\cdot a^0+b^{n-2}a^1+b^{n-3}a^2+\cdots+b^0\cdot a^{n-1}<nb^{n-1}$

Comment: That's exactly the way I thought to myself. However, I've been taking it for granted without even thinking about why it works. Can you make it more clear by using axioms of ordered field and other properties?